# Connect to lan database using python

Tags: python, sql, localhost

I have set up xampp to both of my PCs with success. When I try to connect to the localhost of PC 1 while I am on PC 1 through python, everything works fine. 
But when I am trying to connect to PC 2 xampp sql I cant get a connection.
I have cofigured xampp to accept connections from other devices in the lan and I can access it perfectly through my web browser but not from my python programm.

This is my code:

```
def GetResults(self):
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='test', password= '123456', host='paraliass-pc', port='3306', database='test')
            cursor = cnx.cursor()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                print("Something is wrong with your username or password")
                self.statusBar().showMessage("Wrong Username or Password")
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                print("Database does not exist")
                self.statusBar().showMessage("Database does not exist")

        if cnx :               
            print("Connected")
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Connected")

        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE NAME LIKE '" + self.textEdit.text() + "%' OR SURNAME LIKE '" + self.textEdit.text() + "%'" + "OR RANK LIKE '" + self.textEdit.text() + "%'")
```

I am getting this error which does not appear when I am connecting to the same pc I am running the program on

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnx' referenced before assignment
```

By the way, if i change the username or password on the localhost to be wrong on purpose, I get the same error.

Comment: Because cnx is only defined if the connection actually succeeds. It seems likely you should return from the method after logging the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider granting privileges to connect remotely to MySQL, and bind MySQL to use the IP address and port of your choosing. By default, MySQL will only listen for connections via localhost/socket.

Comment: @dmarvelous How do I do that? from phpmyadmin local webpage? I have edited the config file and added "Allow From All" but still nothing

Comment: Regretfully, this is not a programming related question and should be asked on server fault. However with that, look into changing mysql's bind address in my.cnf

Comment: @dmarvelous I chnaged the ip to : 192.168.1.6 and uncommented the section but still nothing.. I cant understand what the problem is...

Comment: Have you restarted mysql? Also, you may need to grant privileges for your new IP and the user/pass you want.

Comment: @dmarvelous But how can I connect from my browser then without any problem if I need to do all these?